# DT::datable manual column width adjustment with Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, dt, column-sizing

I would like to know if a DT::datatable output object's columns can be automatically adjusted inside a Shiny App? This seems like a very popular interface but I can't seem to do a simple manual column size adjustment, like the Rhandsontable, with the following call

```
hot_cols(manualColumnResize = TRUE)
```

If there is an option to do this via JavaScript I'll take that as well, as I've already search for how to do this with pure R syntax to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: can you post an example of DT usage, where the column is not adjusting? maybe a screenshot with arrows to point where you want it be?

Comment: Think about Excel column how you can move left and right. Can this be replicated in DT?

Comment: Do you mean you want to resize the column width individually or drag columns to different places to reorder them?

Comment: resize column width

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I understand now, not from `DT`, but you could use {[DataEditR](https://github.com/DillonHammill/DataEditR)} package instead.

[image]